# Entity Framework 4, MOQ,

Tags: entity-framework, entity, moq

I am using EF4, Microsoft.Entity.CTP, and the latest MOQ. I am trying to create a generic repository class and moq the DBContext using MOQ. Whenever I run my moq test I get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on this.context.Set().Add(entity); and I don't understand why. The code runs ok without a moq.

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private IContext context;

    public GenericRepository(IContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IList<TEntity> List
    {
        get { return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList(); }
    }

    public void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

var mock = new Mock<IContext>();
GenericRepository<Product> producRepository = new GenericRepository<Product>(mock.Object);

mock.Setup(x => x.Product.Add(productType));
mock.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges());

productRepository.Create(product);
mock.VerifyAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock out the list implementation behind Set.  I'm not at the compute ATM but iirc it's an IDbSet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  On the DbContext object its a concrete class.   public DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;.  How can I mock this?

Comment: DbSet isn't a sealed class so you can Mock it out as you would an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code first definitions from DbSet to IDbSet and then you can mock them.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/21/productivity-improvements-for-the-entity-framework.aspx

I am considering changing my DbContext.tt file to generate IDbSet instead of DbSet, but only after I get the mocking to work.

I am not saying this makes the rest of the work easy, but it will get you past one problem.
What I need help with is what to do after changing my code first definitions to be based on the EF DbContext interfaces.  For example, I create instances of my DbSet objects and add them.

```
Mock<IPosManContext> posManContext;

posManContext.Object.Set(typeof(note_template));

posManContext.Object.note_template.Add(
    new note_template()
    {
        note_template_id = 1,
        act_flag = "Y",
        desc_text = "Monday Monday",
        last_update_dtm = now,
        last_update_user_id = "hsimpson",
    });
```

But I get an error that the DbSet is null.

Microsoft needs to provide a good example of what to do.
They went half the way by providing public interfaces for mocking, but I still need more help.

Joe